# Fired datatrigger is not changing custom control's property(ControlTemplate)

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate, datatrigger

I Want to change  a DependcyProperty(Named is as `MessageTemplateProperty`) which is in CustomControl and Type is `Controltemplate` .

**But I can't set the value to it using `datatrigger`**

But another DependcyProperty(named as `IsShowMessageProperty`)  which is in CustomControl and Type is `bool` can be set using datatrigger.

**Who can explain it ,Why, and How to solve it.**

#### The Custom Code as follow:

```
public class MessageOverLay : ContentControl
{
    static MessageOverLay()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MessageOverLay),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MessageOverLay)));
    }

    #region DependcyProperties

    // Template attached property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MessageTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(MessageOverLay),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(MessageTemplateChanged));

    public ControlTemplate MessageTemplate
    {
        set{SetValue(MessageTemplateProperty, value);}
        get{return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(MessageTemplateProperty);}
     }

    // IsVisible attached property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsShowMessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsShowMessage", typeof(bool), typeof(MessageOverLay),
            new PropertyMetadata(IsShowMessageChanged));

    public bool IsShowMessage
    {
        get{return (bool)GetValue(IsShowMessageProperty);}
        set{SetValue(IsShowMessageProperty, value);}
    }


    #endregion DependcyProperties



}
```

#### The Custom Default Theme Generic.xaml

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MessageOverLay}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:MessageOverLay">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter  x:Name="PART_Conent"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

                                         Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        <Control x:Name="Part_MessageControl" Template="{TemplateBinding MessageTemplate}" 
                                 Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsShowMessage,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="MessageTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Grid Width="150" Height="100" Margin="5  0 0 10">
                        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" Margin="0 20 0 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="What are you doing?" Margin="5 25 0 0" />
                        <Button Content="Cancel" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <Button Content="OK" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### I Want to use it as follow:

Demo XAML:

```
  <Window ...>
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="GenderPopupTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid Width="200" Height="100" Margin=" 5 0 0 10">              
                <TextBlock Text="Please Select Gender " Margin="5 25 0 0" />
                <Button Content="Male" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Command="{Binding SelectedGenderCommand}" />
                <Button Content="FeMale" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Command="{Binding SelectedGenderCommand}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FacePopupTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid Width="200" Height="100" Margin="5 10 0 0">
                <TextBlock Text="Do you like your Face,Now?" Margin="5 25 0 0" />
                <Button Content="OK" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Command="{Binding OKCommand}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

    <controls:MessageOverLay  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              MessageTemplate="{StaticResource GenderPopupTemplate}"
                             IsShowMessage="True">
        <controls:MessageOverLay.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MessageOverLay}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageBoxType}" Value="{x:Static viewModels:MessageBoxTypes.SelectView}">
                        <Setter Property="MessageTemplate" Value="{StaticResource GenderPopupTemplate}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="350"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageBoxType}" Value="{x:Static viewModels:MessageBoxTypes.MessageView}">
                        <Setter Property="MessageTemplate" Value="{StaticResource FacePopupTemplate}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </controls:MessageOverLay.Style>
        <Grid  Background="SeaGreen" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
        </Grid>
    </controls:MessageOverLay>
```

I want to change the MessageTemplate when the Propery `MessageBoxType` of `MainWindowViewModel` changed.
But I can't archive it.

#### The other related code

Demo C# Code:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand SelectedGenderCommand { get; }

    public ICommand OKCommand { get; }

    private MessageBoxTypes _messageBoxType;

    public MessageBoxTypes MessageBoxType
    {
        get { return _messageBoxType; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _messageBoxType, value); }
    }

    private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MessageBoxType = MessageBoxTypes.SelectView;

        SelectedGenderCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(SelectedGender);

        OKCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OK);
    }

    private void OK(object obj)
    {
        MessageBoxType = MessageBoxTypes.SelectView;
    }

    private void SelectedGender(object obj)
    {
        MessageBoxType = MessageBoxTypes.MessageView;
    }
}

public enum MessageBoxTypes
{
    SelectView,
    MessageView,
    ConfirmView
}
```

Update:

[Here](https://github.com/huoxudong125/HQF.WPF.OverLay/tree/master) is the full demo code in github ,Please check it.

Comment: You have declared your dependency properties with static getter and setter methods, while there should be a CLR property wrapper (e.g. a `MessageTemplate` property). Besides that, it isn't clear how the MessageTemplate property is actually used (or meant to be used) by your control.

Comment: @Clemens no ,I haven't implement the  CLR property wrapper (e.g. a MessageTemplate property).but `IsShowMessageProperty`  the same as the `MessageTemplateProperty `

Comment: Sure, why didn't you do it?

Comment: @I just use these property in XAML.NOT in C# Code.

Comment: That doesn't matter. A valid dependency property declaration requires the CLR wrapper. And again, it isn't clear how the MessageTemplate property is actually used (or meant to be used) by your control.

Comment: @Clemens 
        after I implement the wrapper ,there is a error when compile the code.

Comment: But you think it isn't necessary to show the changed code and tell us about the exact error message and where it occurs, right?

Comment: @Clemens I will share the demo code .

Comment: @Clemens I have add the full demo code in [github](https://github.com/huoxudong125/HQF.WPF.OverLay/tree/master) please check it

Comment: Sorry. I won't check your code on github. If you want help at StackOverflow, you'll have to post the relevant parts of your code here in your question.

Comment: @Clemens OK, I have updated the question ,to add more code ,Thanks

Comment: Now you *still* haven't told us about the compiler error message. I can however see that `return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(IsShowMessageProperty);` in the MessageTemplate getter is wrong. As a general note, please try to rewrite your question in a way that is comprehensible for others. Remove irrelevant parts and concentrate on the relevant things. Explain what you are trying to achieve, what behavior your expect and how the observed behavior differs from that. Take a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to ask a good question.

Comment: And replace *all* the static getter and setter method by properties!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a dependency property is to be set by a Style Setter, there must be no direct assignment of a so-called local value, as you do in

```
<controls:MessageOverLay MessageTemplate="{StaticResource GenderPopupTemplate}" ...>
```

The directly assigned local value always has higher precedence than any value from Style Setters (and other possible sources), so that the Setter has no effect. More details can be found here: [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

Replace the direct assignment be another Style Setter:

```
 <controls:MessageOverLay  ...>
    <controls:MessageOverLay.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MessageOverLay}">

            <Setter Property="MessageTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource GenderPopupTemplate}"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                ...
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </controls:MessageOverLay.Style>
    ...
</controls:MessageOverLay>
```

Comment: Thanks,I will read more detail about how to make a WPF Cutom Control. By The way ,I use your open source [XAML Map Control](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/)  too.